# How to read only first n lines from large xlsx in angular 5?

Tags: javascript, angular5, xlsx

I am trying to display in the front end few lines of data from xlsx file. I want to read first n lines from excel file because if I read total excel file that will take a lot of time and that is not required. For that, I am doing slice operation with 5kb. It is working if the file size is below 5k(because I am reading full excel) but it is not working above 5kb. I am able to see in console this error.

Error: Corrupted zip: can't find end of central directory

You can check my code below. I am passing the file to readFile function. I have given the sudo code of my program below.

```
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';
function readFile(file)
{ 
    var myReader: FileReader = new FileReader();
    let slice_file = file.slice(0, 1024*5);
    //console.log(slice_file);
    let workbook: any;       
    myReader.readAsArrayBuffer(slice_file)
    myReader.onload = (e) => {
       try{  
              workbook = XLSX.read(myReader.result, { type: "array" });
       }catch(e){
              console.log(e);
          }

    }
    //I will use workbook here
}
```

As of I know this will not work out because without reading the full size of the file it will be like a corrupted file. I don't want to read the total file. I tried with file reader using binary format also I converted the myReader result to binary and tried to read with XLXS but no use.